# Comment flag declined, yet comment was removed

Tags: discussion, comments, declined-flags

I flagged a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51388805/1889329) as *"rude or abusive"*. I don't recall the entire contents, but it contained the phrase

> get offa my lawn whippersnapper

The flag was declined, yet the comment was removed. What happened? I'm particularly interested in these questions:

- Can flags only be declined by a moderator?
- If so, why was the flag declined, yet the comment removed?
- If this turns out to have been a mistake, can the flag be accepted (so that I don't get annoying *"Your last flag was declined..."* messages)?

Comment: "Could you please consider stepping on vegetation elsewhere?"

Comment: @Felix you're missing a nice rephrasing of 'whippersnapper' in there ;)

Comment: What the heck are you doing?  I've seen you getting into nasty pointless comment debates for, oh, a least a month.  Considerably elevated from the usual level.  I detest seeing them in my inbox, give me a break too.  If you are mad about something then just spit it out and get it over with.

Comment: @HansPassant: I am asking a genuine question. There is no immediate need to leave a non-constructive comment, informing me how much you dislike non-constructive comments. Just submit your vote and move on. Not a big fan of your I-know-what's-best-for-you attitude either, in case you are wondering.

Comment: Just say "get off my lawn".  Carries the same message but without the explicit vitriol.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A moderator declined the flag, then deleted the comment.

They probably declined the flag (and I would have too), because the comment is *not rude or abusive*. *Get offa my lawn* is a tongue-in-cheek expression, a mock gruff admission of feeling old. The author made a harmless joke *at their own expense*. To quote the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=get%20off%20my%20lawn):

> A tagline added to posts that reveal the author's age, **which is higher than he/she would otherwise care to admit.**

They were feeling old because they are realising that others don’t think of the CLR as “new”. Nothing more. I note that the comment even included a smiley face and sound effects!

> @IInspectable I said ne**wer**. Get offa my lawn, whippersnapper, grumble grumble. :)

Extrapolating further, I think they then deleted the comment since *you* apparently didn't like it enough to flag it as rude, so as to avoid further umbrage.

> - Can flags only be declined by a moderator?

Yes, only moderators can decline flags.

> - If this turns out to have been a mistake, can the flag be accepted (so that I don't get annoying "Your last flag was declined..." messages)?

No, once a flag is handled the status can't be changed.

Comment: Tongue-in-cheek or otherwise, the intent was clear: *"Go away!"*. That *is* rude. If you and your gang no longer find that rude, let me know, so I can start posting genuine requests for feedback to questions again (such as *"What is your question?"* - a comment (verbatim) that was deleted as *"rude or abusive"* by you, or one of your co-mods).

Comment: No, sorry. That comment does not, to me, tell you to “go away”. It really just means that they are suddenly feeling old. Please don’t read anything more into it.

Comment: It requires cultural context to *not* read anything into that comment. If you lack cultural context, and take the comment at face value, it is rude. I am in the latter group, and the moderator apparently was in the former, not even knowing that *they* were reading something into the comment while handling the flag. Oh well, there will be more *"Welcome Wagon"* type blog entries.

Answer (score 8):

> Can flags only be declined by a moderator?

Comment flags can only be declined by a moderator.

> If so, why was the flag declined, yet the comment removed?

Perhaps the post author removed it.  Or perhaps the moderator felt it merited deletion, but not for the reason stated?  For example, they may have felt that it was merely no longer necessary, not abusive.  That's the most likely option.

> If this turns out to have been a mistake, can the flag be accepted (so that I don't get annoying "Your last flag was declined..." messages)?

No.  The message will go away either after it's been a while, or after another flag of yours is accepted.

Comment: It's also simply not possible for a mod to change a ruling on a flag after the fact... another option is "the moderator accidentally declined the flag but realized later that the comment should have been deleted." Mods are humans, too. :) OP removing the comment would have marked it as helpful, pretty sure.

Comment: If the post author removed it, wouldn't the flag automatically get promoted to the accepted state? And if a moderator feels, that a contribution is both no longer needed *and* rude/abusive, why would they opt to remove it as *"no longer needed"*?

Comment: @IInspectable If the author removed it *before* a moderator handled the flag, then yes.  If the deleted it *after*, then no.  If the moderator felt that reason applied *and* another reason applied, then sure, they'd accept the flag.  If they felt that your flag was wrong, they'll declined the flag, even if some other action is merited.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that as a non-mod, my reasons as to the "decline" are an assumption, and may be completely wrong. Only the mod who acted on the flag can tell us 100% for sure why it was declined. With that in mind:

> Can flags only be declined by a moderator?

Comment flags, yes. For the majority of cases, the same is true of post flags. (Instead, you'll get "disputed.")

> If so, why was the flag declined, yet the comment removed?

It could quite easily be that the comment was not needed, though I'm not sure why the phrase you quote would be "rude or abusive" as it is.  It may be that the mod declined this flag to point out to you that you used the wrong flag. As far as I'm aware, that's not incredibly common for comment flags, but it could be a result of the current look into comments and how "unwelcoming" they are.

It could also be that the mod clicked the wrong button, as they felt the comment did need to go even if they disagreed with the flag, but they still deleted the comment because... Well, it needed to go.

> If this turns out to have been a mistake, can the flag be accepted (so that I don't get annoying "Your last flag was declined..." messages)?

Flag statuses cannot be changed after the fact, minus one or two specific exceptions for post flags. The message will (eventually) go away, sooner rather than later if you flag (correctly) a lot.

Comment: Even post flags can't be declined by non-mods, only disputed. :)

Comment: @Catija There's one or two cases where they can be declined by non-mods. For the most part, though, that's true enough.

Comment: *"I'm not sure why the phrase you quote would be "rude or abusive" as it is"* - Er... that's unexpected.

Comment: @IInspectable I put that I wasn't sure specifically because... Well, what you quoted doesn't, without context, seem rude _to me._ But, that is 1) possibly because of where I'm at and the culture around that joke in my area, and 2) possibly because of missing context that _did_ make what you flagged rude. As I warned at the top of my answer... I may be completely wrong in my assumptions.

Comment: If it requires context to *not* take the phrase as rude, then by itself it is, no?

Comment: @IInspectable Um... That's actually the reverse of what I was trying to convey. Without context, it _doesn't_ seem rude to me. With context, it may very well have been rude, but by itself the phrase does not seem rude. Having context wouldn't make it not rude to me, it would _potentially_ make it actually rude.

Comment: You *are* having context (apparently some culture around *"that"* joke). Maybe you don't realize that this *is* context. Context that others may not have. Now try putting yourself in a situation, where you don't have that context, and read the phrase again.

Comment: @IInspectable Ah, okay, you're meaning a different context than I. Honestly, I currently don't have the context to _see_ it as rude- I'm not sure how it _could_ be rude. You mention others might not have my cultural context- At the moment, I don't have the cultural context you suggest I should use. The context _I_ meant was that around the joke itself- How it was said and used.